# How would one do two way data binding with react, having an input value A update when B is, and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, reactjs

Currently I have the following code:

```js
var Text = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
      return {
          pageName: this.props.pageName,
          url:  this.props.pageName,
      }
  },
  handleChange: function(){
      var pageName = this.refs.pageName.getDOMNode().value;
      var url      = this.refs.url.getDOMNode().value;
      this.setState({
          pageName: pageName,
          url: url,
              });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
        pageName: <input ref="pageName" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.url}/><br/>
        url: <input ref="url" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.pageName.toLowerCase()}/><br/>
        </div>);
  }
});

React.render(<Text pageName="name" url="url" />, document.body);
```

As you can see from the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5d6jhhb/30/) here, it is does not work as expected. I was wondering if someone could illuminate me on the topic. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want changes to pageName to update url, and vice versa, then you probably want to do something like this:

```
var Text = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
      return {
          pageName: this.props.pageName,
          url:  this.props.pageName,
      }
  },
  handleChange: function(event){
      var pageName = event.target.value;
      var url      = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
      this.setState({
          pageName: pageName,
          url: url,
              });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
        pageName: <input ref="pageName" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.pageName}/><br/>
        url: <input ref="url" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.url}/><br/>
        </div>);
  }
});

React.render(<Text pageName="name" />, document.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a few errors. This works as expected.

```
    var Text = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function(){
          return {
              pageName: this.props.pageName,
              url:  this.props.url,
          }
      },
      handlePageChange: function(event){
          this.setState({pageName: event.target.value});
      },
        handleUrlChange: function(event){
          this.setState({url: event.target.value});
      },
      render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
            pageName: <input ref="pageName" onChange={this.handlePageChange} value={this.state.pageName.toLowerCase()}/><br/>
            url: <input ref="url" onChange={this.handleUrlChange} value={this.state.url}/><br/>
            </div>);
      }
    });

    React.render(<Text pageName="name" url="url" />, document.body);
```

Comment: When I try this in Fiddle, it does no double binding: typing in url does not update pageName or vice versa.

Comment: Are these two distinct values or are they one value displaying as mixed case and lower case?